# find domain of $\int\arccos \left(\sqrt{\frac{x-4}{x+6}}\right)$

Tags: integration, integral-domain

How can i find domain of this integral?
$$\int\arccos\left(\sqrt{\frac{x-4}{x+6}}\right)dx$$

I tried this:

$$\frac{x-4}{x+6}\ge0\implies (-\infty,-6)\cup [4,\infty)$$
Next:

$$-1\le\sqrt{\frac{x-4}{x+6}}\le1$$
Can I do something like that? 
$-1\le\sqrt{\frac{x-4}{x+6}}$ $\cap\sqrt{\frac{x-4}{x+6}}\le1$

Comment: You want $\left| \sqrt{\frac{x-4}{x+6}}\right| \leq 1$, so (since both sides are nonnegative we can square), $\left|\frac{x-4}{x+6}\right| \leq 1$ and thus $|x-4|\leq |x+6|$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the first constraint you have
$$
\frac{x-4}{x+6} \ge 0
$$
and from the second one,
$$
\left| \frac{x-4}{x+6} \right| \le 1 \Leftrightarrow -1 \le \frac{x-4}{x+6} \le 1
$$
and you need the intersection of both, yielding
$$
0 \le \frac{x-4}{x+6} \le 1.
$$

Can you solve this?

Comment: Ok it means that i can solve like this?
$$0 \le \frac{x-4}{x+6}  \cap \frac{x-4}{x+6} \le 1$$

Comment: @DavidM yes, it does